# Problem in writing \alpha and \beta in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, tex

I am plotting curves using [Getdist](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html) inside the `jupyter`. For labeling the parameters I have a problem.
I write `\zeta`, `\chi`, `\gamma`, `\Omega`, `\omega` and I have no problem in them and the symbolic shape of them appear without no problem, but as I want to write `\beta` and `\alpha` I get some errors

this is part of the too long error

```
ValueError: 
$lpha$
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

This is part of the related code:

```
g.triangle_plot([samples0],['H_0','\Omega_D','b','aa','\alpha','M','t']
```

I really do not understand the issue, and I am confused.

Comment: `\ ` escapes the next character in a string, try writing it like this `r'\Omega_D'` or double the backslashes like this `'\\Omega_D'`

Comment: @reportgunner Oh thanks, it worked. Why this happens to some letter like `alph`? I mean `\` works for some other letter like `omega` but about `alpha` it has problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because `'\a'` is a string literal for ascii character 7 [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/) just like `'\t'` is for tab and `'\n'` is for newline.

we can check this using the built-in function `ord()` which returns the corresponding ASCII table index for the supplied character - [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

```
>>> ord('\a')
7
>>> ord('\n')
10
>>> ord('\t')
9
```

on the other hand, `'\o'` doesn't correspond to any character.

```
>>> ord('\o')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

to get around this, just prepend `r`(as in `raw string`) before the string like this

`my_string_variable = r'alpha\omega'`